# How to zoom web view dynamically in android using action bar, onNavigationItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-actionbar

[image: I want to zoom 125% ,150%....]

In my application I used action bar and web view.
I want to zoom my web view 125% ,150%....
So please help me to find out solution.

Comment: Me too Suffering from same problem...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by only in android API 21 and after by using this function

```
mWebView.zoomBy(2.0f); //here 2.0f means 200%.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
mWebView.zoomIn();

mWebView.zoomOut();
```

Comment: Did you read question fully? He wants to implement zoom with particular percentage.

Comment: mWebView.setInitialScale(150) that means 150%

Comment: Where have you mentioned this in the answer? That's what my previous comment is about.